# Repeating large elements in a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
_parser = re.compile('''
                    (?P<a>-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(/-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)?)?x[+\-]
                    (?P<b>-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(/-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)?)?y[+\-]
                    (?P<c>-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(/-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)?)?=0
                    ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

This quite obviously has a lot of repetition in it, so it got me wondering, what's the syntax (if it exists) to repeat blocks of similar expressions in a single expression?

Comment: The language of the question is python, but I can understand enough Java to understand your answer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

Surround `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(/-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)` in another capture group, and then refer to it with `\2`, since it's the second open-paren in the regex:

```
_parser = re.compile('''
     (?P<a>-?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(/-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))?)?)?x[+\-]
              (?P<b>-?\2?)?)?y[+\-]
                (?P<c>-?\2?)?)?=0
                ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

You could also do this by creating the string of the regex, and then using that string-variable repeatedly. I don't know Python, but in Java it'd be something like this:

```
String sRegexPiece = "[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?(/-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)";
String sRegexWhole = "(?P<a>-?" + sRegexPiece + "?)?x[+\-]" + sLS + //sLS: line separator
    "(?P<b>-?" + sRegexPiece + "?)?)?y[+\-]" + sLS + 
    "(?P<c>-?" + sRegexPiece + "?)?)?=0" + sLS + 
    "'''";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sRegexWhole);
```

Comment: Seems like what you really want is to use parser combinators; does such a library exist for Python?

Comment: The first part of your answer is false `\2` is a backreference and refers to the content machted by the second capturing group, it doesn't refer to the subpattern itself.

Comment: Well, I think "wrong" is too strong a word, because it is possible that the same content is acceptable in those spots. But I agree that the string-concatenation version (the second half of my answer) is the way to go.

Comment: An other possibility is to use the regex module (the Python futur module for regex) instead of the re module. With this module, you can reuse a subpattern with `(?2)`.